# Why does MacOs ssh give different permissions to batch and interactive mode?

Tags: macos, ssh, interactive

I'm trying to install a gem remotely on several machines, but I get different behaviour when I run interactively (it works) or when it's in batch (permission denied):

```
$ ssh qa@192.168.19.82 'gem install iStats'
Warning: Permanently added '192.168.19.82' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0 directory.

$ ssh qa@192.168.19.82
Warning: Permanently added '192.168.19.82' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
Last login: Thu Jan 26 10:50:17 2017 from 192.168.21.168
qa$ gem install iStats
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed iStats-1.4.0
Parsing documentation for iStats-1.4.0
Done installing documentation for iStats after 0 seconds
1 gem installed

qa$ id
uid=502(qa) gid=20(staff) groups=20(staff),12(everyone),61(localaccounts),79(_appserverusr),80(admin),81(_appserveradm),98(_lpadmin),33(_appstore),100(_lpoperator),204(_developer),395(com.apple.access_ftp),101(com.apple.access_screensharing-disabled),102(com.apple.access_ssh-disabled)
qa$ logout
Connection to 192.168.19.82 closed.

$ ssh qa@192.168.19.82 'id'
Warning: Permanently added '192.168.19.82' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
uid=502(qa) gid=20(staff) groups=20(staff),12(everyone),61(localaccounts),79(_appserverusr),80(admin),81(_appserveradm),98(_lpadmin),33(_appstore),100(_lpoperator),204(_developer),395(com.apple.access_ftp),101(com.apple.access_screensharing-disabled),102(com.apple.access_ssh-disabled)
```

I found that this works:

```
$ echo ' gem install iStats; exit ' | ssh -t -t qa@192.168.19.82
Warning: Permanently added '192.168.19.82' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
Last login: Thu Jan 26 11:40:31 2017 from 192.168.21.168
qa$ gem install iStats
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed iStats-1.4.0
Parsing documentation for iStats-1.4.0
Done installing documentation for iStats after 0 seconds
1 gem installed
logout
```

... but I'm surprised at *permissions* changing based on tty.

Is this Apple being weird again, or is this normal and I've just missed it?

Answer (score 0):

When running a command directly as in your first example, your shell (Bash by default) does not run in interactive mode which skips some initialization scripts, most prominently, `~/.bash_profile`.

Now, if you installed your Ruby via e.g. RVM or rbenv, it is very likely it won't be found here since both options require changes to the `$PATH` of the running shell.

Because of that, when trying to install the gem in your first example, you attempt to install it globally to the system-provided Ruby. This requires you to be root which is why this fails.